# Git Bash in Windows doesn't remember aliases

Tags: git, git-bash

I have created some aliases to simplify some commands in git bash. But when I restart the git bash, it actually forgets all the aliases.

I have tried the .bash_profile hack. But it's not working.

Comment: Did you use the "touch" command on your .bash_proifle file before you had added your aliases?

Answer (score 1):

Profile files aren't a hack. You have to find out where this port of Bash is looking for the `.bashrc` file. Chances are that it's taking the home directory from either the `HOME` environment variable or `USERPROFILE`. Unfortunately, the "Git for Windows" port of bash doesn't seem read the home directory `.bashrc`, even though it writes `.bash_history`.

In the version I have installed, the existing aliases, come from the file `etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`, in the installation root. For example, `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`. You can put your own `.sh` script into this directory.